# Exchange files with computer and android tablet

Tags: permissions, android, tablet

I try to transfer some files to my samsung tablet. First I connected my computer and the tablet via USB.

Then this menu appeared.

[image]

Now I tried to copy a html project to the tablet. First I created the directory "stelen" on the tablet.

Then I opened a terminal inside the root folder of the tablet and executed the following command to copy the project to the tablet:

```
sudo cp -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/stelen_gallery_v2/ stelen
```

[image]

But I get `could not access stelen, no permission`. The tablet is unlocked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the user owning the directory `stelen` the same as your user?<br>What about `/opt/lampp/htdocs/stelen_gallery_v2/`? Directories in `/opt/` are usually root-owned.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I censored the username because of privacy. Just pretend that the user is `blck`.  The user and group is  `blck:blck` for every file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.

1. Install **mtpfs** `sudo apt-get install mtpfs`
2. Install **jmtpfs** `sudo apt-get install jmtpfs`
3. Connect the device with your computer via USB and unlock the device.
4. If the device was detected and appears in the sidebar then right click on it and select unmount.
5. Create mount point in home directory:    `mkdir ~/android`
6. Mount the device into the new mountpoint: `jmtpfs ~/android`

Something like this should appear:

```
root@pc:/# jmtpfs ~/android
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
```

Now you have access to the device!

8. After you finished all file transfers, unmount the device. `fusermount -u ~/android`

More Infos (german)
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MTP/